# Javascript runs on an HTML Page but Not on WordPress

Tags: javascript, html

I installed a javascript on an HTML page and it works perfectly - you can see it here - http://source-pro.org/PPT-Calc-Windows.html

The same code when added to a WordPress Page utilizing a Custom Field does not work - you can see it here - http://source-pro.org/inches-to-pixels-and-saving/

This is the code

```js
var vals = [1/3, 2/3, 3/3, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 4/4];
var tmp = 0;
    str += '\nValue display using .toFixed(3) then truncates\n';
for (var i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
  tmp = vals[i].toFixed(3);
  str += tmp.substr(0,tmp.length-1)+'\n';
}

document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = str;

function compute_p (obj) {
  with (Math) {
    u4=eval(obj.einh.value);
    d4=eval(obj.cmheight1.value);
    d5=eval(obj.cmwidth1.value);
    d8=eval(obj.cmresolution.value);
    if (obj.einh[1].checked) {
      h5=d4*d8;
      h6=d5*d8;
    } else {
      h5=(d4/2.54)*d8;
      h6=(d5/2.54)*d8;
    }
    s1=((h5*h6*3)/1024)/1024;
    s2=round(h5)*round(h6);

    function rounder(x,stellen) {
      return (Math.round(x*Math.pow(10,stellen)))/Math.pow(10,stellen)
    }

    obj.res5.value =round(h5);
    obj.res6.value =round(h6);
    obj.sres.value =rounder(s1,2);
    obj.sres_pix.value =round(s2);
  }
}
function compute (obj) {
  with (Math) {
    d1=eval(obj.height1.value);
    d2=eval(obj.width1.value);
    d3=eval(obj.resolution.value=96);
    h1=(d1/d3)*2.54;
    h2=(d2/d3)*2.54;
    h3=d1/d3;
    h4=d2/d3;
    tmp = h3.toFixed(4);
    obj.res3.value = tmp.substr(0,tmp.length-1)+'\n';
    tmp = h4.toFixed(4);
    obj.res4.value = tmp.substr(0,tmp.length-1)+'\n';
  }
}
```

Can anyone see anything that would cause this code to fail when in WordPress?

This is what the error console displays "str is not defined." for both the version on a straight html page AND in WordPress and yet the code works just fine on the straight html page.

I'm confused

Comment: JavaScripts in WP usually need to be enqueued. How are you including your code in WP?

Comment: Inspect the head of your html, is the file there? Put an alert statement anywhere, is it firing?